# Como recuperar valores em um relacionamento hasMany em laravel

Tags: laravel

Pessoal eu tenho a seguinte função dentro de uma Model Campaign.

```
  public function success_payments(){

        return $this->hasMany(Payment::class)->whereStatus('3');
    }
```

Essa função retorna os valores da tabela Payment que tenham status = 3.

Depois utilizo uma variável para retornar os valores dessa tabela somando os valores do campos amount.

```
$raised = $this->success_payments()->sum('amount');
```

Até ai tudo certo, estava atendendo as minhas necessidades, mas agora surgiu a necessidade de recuperar mais um campo da tabela Payment chamado updated_at que um campo do tipo date, e com esse campo fazer uma logica onde eu consiga somar a esse campo 14 dias a mais, e retornar na variável $raised ou criar outra variável, somente os valores onde o valor do campo updated_at somado 14 dias seja maior ou igual a data atual.

Não sei se ficou claro minha dúvida.

É que anteriormente eu usava um gatway de pagamento, e agora estou usando um novo gatway de pagamento onde o dinheiro é liberado somente 14 dias apos confirmação do pagamento, então preciso mostrar ao Usuário apenas os valores que tenham o status igual a 3, que é pago, e que tenha a data da mudança de status somando 14 dias.

Agradeço pelo ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Todos relacionamentos se recupera da seguinte forma:

```
Model::with('relacionamento')->sum('column'); //Dentro do with é o nome da função que criou no controller por exemplo

public function user() {
   return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class);
}

Model::with('user')->sum('column');
```

não importa qual relacionamento fez só usar o with